# How to make sure commands are not repeated in docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am learning about build image using docker file.

**short description of what I have done**

**step 1**

For making testing I have started on build image using below docker file

```
FROM centos:6.8
MAINTAINER Bilal Usean "xxxxx@xxx.xxx"
RUN yum install -y httpd; yum -y clean all
```

after that I have run the below command

```
docker build -t httpd/centos:6.8 .
```

it is successfully install apache in httpd/centos:6.8 image

**step 2**

Next I am trying to install jdk in the same existing newly created image

```
FROM centos:6.8
MAINTAINER Bilal Usean "xxxxxx@xxx@xx"
RUN yum install -y httpd; yum -y clean all
yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel; yum -y clean all
```

after that I have run the below command

```
docker build -t httpd/centos:6.8 .
```

But It will start from again httpd install, I expected it will skip that httpd step for already install.

I think it is not a good practice to make docker file.I have 20 **RUN** command in docker file, that is download heavy size file from net so I want to make sure about it each command success. otherwise it will fail intermediately and again it will charge more MB.

**note:** If I am in the wrong way, please describe the best way to deal with image and docker file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It repeats here because you did not add another `RUN` command, but appended (and changed) the previous command (docker detects this change, and runs the new command).

What you should be writing is:

```
FROM centos:6.8
MAINTAINER Bilal Usean "xxxxxxxx@xxx.xxx"
RUN yum install -y httpd; yum -y clean all
RUN yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel; yum -y clean all
```

Comment: You can tell if it's working as expected by looking for the "Using cache" output like: `Step 2 : RUN yum install -y httpd; yum -y clean all
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 9df171dc34e5`